# Why is the past form of 来た in this sentence? About something that is coming next?

Tags: past

The character is watching a firework show. From what I gather from the next sequence, the fireworks are shot in sequence (連発)

BEFORE the sequence itself happens, the character says this:

> 連発来たかも!

My understanding from context is that he's wondering if the 連発 are coming next. However, why is the past form used?

Given he's speculating if the next firework will be 連発, should it not the

> 連発来るかも!

Why is the past form used for a sequence that has yet to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English speakers also say "The time has come" immediately before something *actually* starts, so this is in the same vein. The speaker noticed something, and *is* thinking the (time for) 連発 might have already arrived.

来るかも would mean "it may (or may not) come (in the future)".